# Ignore values from stringstream (like %*f in sscanf)

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm trying to get rid of old unsafe C functions, including sscanf(). Right now I'm using

```
#include <sstream>
std::string str = "111 222.2 333 444.4 555";
std::stringstream sstr(str);
int i, j, k;
float dummy1, dummy2;
sstr >> i >> dummy1 >> j >> dummy2 >> k;
```

I just need the integers from that. Is there any way to avoid those nasty dummy variables?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sstr.ignore(128,' ');`

Ignore until next space, or until 128 characters were read.

Comment: I agree - is there not a way to do this without an arbitrary constant?

Comment: If you know for sure you are looking for a delimiter, you can use ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),':');

Answer (score 3):

You can get by with a single dummy (per type):

```
std::string str("111 222.2 333 444.4 555");
std::stringstream sstr(str);
int i, j, k;
float dummy;
sstr >> i >> dummy >> j >> dummy >> k;
```

Comment: This works, but seems so clumsy - is there not something like ss >> a >> ignore >> b; ?